# Upgrading a old MFC project and change it to use MFC shared Lib

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mfc

I have a old MFC App (vc6) that used "MFC dll lib" and use other MFC Projects that link them via dlls(statically) not extension dll.

I upgraded the App to VC14 and successfully compiled it and run it.  But when change the properties to  "use MFC shared lib" I get this assertion:

> ASSERT(AfxGetThread() == NULL) in CWinApp appcore.cpp.

and when put break point at `CWinApp::CWinApp` I see that all my Dlls arrived to there.

Please help to me.

Comment: Take a look: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f7ck28

Comment: @dude What, specifically, are we supposed to look at? Herzl, my guess would be that you have a DLL that is initializing the thread before your main application, which the framework is trying to protect you from doing. It's going to be rather difficult for us to debug this remotely, without seeing any of the code. Do your DLLs arrive in `CWinApp::CWinApp` before the application? DLLs should *never* instantiate a `CWinApp` class! Of course, that was true even back in VC6, but perhaps the library didn't have debug code to catch this error?

Comment: @CodyGray You wrote "DLLs should never instantiate a CWinApp class! ". And exactly this message you can find in my linked article: "Extension DLLs should not instantiate a class derived from CWinApp, but should rely on the client application (or DLL) to provide this object.". But that is only one point, better to read whole article.

Comment: yes my Dlls drived from CWinApp and arived before. " DLLs should never instantiate" this say that my dll class can't drived from a CWinApp?

Comment: @CodyGray how can I to perevent from a dll to initializing the thread before main app?

Comment: when that create a dll project for MFC main class in project inherit from CwinApp and when I put a break point in CWinApp arrive there only once from main application project

Comment: and I don't use Extension  dlls

Comment: @CodyGray: MFC took an unfortunate shortcut to implementing [module states of a regular DLL dynamically linked to MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w25be484.aspx) by re-using the `CWinApp` class for regular DLLs. Although I don't follow the logic (it actually reads like the solution - giving each module its own copy of the global state information - *is* the problem that needed to be solved). I do have distant recollections, that regular DLLs in MFC needed to implement their own `CWinApp`-derived class.

Comment: Oh, you're right @IInspectable, they did re-use the class for DLLs. I can't remember the details, either. I still have MFC apps, but I don't use MFC DLLs. The design is quite confusing. It appears that a regular (non-extension) MFC DLL has its own instance of a CWinApp object that actually acts as a proxy to the original object. The issue here is probably static linking vs dynamic linking, but there aren't enough details in the question for me to reproduce the problem, so all I can do is guess.

Comment: The fact that this is an upgrade from MSVC 6 may be another clue. `AfxGetThread` in the implementation of MFC shipped with MSVC 6 and earlier calls `AfxGetApp` if it does not find a thread. On later versions of MFC, `AfxGetThread` simply returns `NULL` if no thread was found. If this was your code, I'd say you need to fix it, but this is library code, so you can't just change it. But that means there is some mismatch of project settings or invalid infrastructure code. Starting with a new DLL template project from the current version of MSVC and copying your code into it should fix the problem.